# XeLaTeX, sans serif math in beamer

Tags: math-mode, xetex, sans-serif

I use the package `cmbright` with `beamer` when I typeset a document with pdflatex. Is there a sans-serif math font to compile a `beamer` presentation with XeLaTeX?

Comment: Not really, you can use the same math fonts you use with pdflatex, but there is yet no sans serif math font which could be used with unicode-math (but there has been a number of requests for such fonts, so there is a bit hope that some will appear in the future),

Comment: OK. Never mind! I will continue with `cmbright` and `pdflatex`.